# What is wrong in my code? I'm having problems using Express and connect mongo

Tags: javascript, express

I can't figure out where the problem is in my code.

This error message appears:

TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'

Can anyone identify the problem? And what would be the solution?

I've been trying to figure out what I did wrong for several hours and I can't figure it out.

```
    require('dotenv').config()
    
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then(() => {
            app.emit('pronto')
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    
    
    const session = require('express-session')
    const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
    
    
    const routes = require('./routes')
    const path = require('path')
    const { middleGlobal } = require('./src/middlewares/middleware')
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')))
    
    const sessionOptions = session({
        secret: 'hdfkajdkk58fj',
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
            httpOnly: true
        }
    })
    
    
    app.use(sessionOptions)
    app.use(flash())
    
    app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'views'))
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
    
    // Nossos próprios middlewares
    app.use(middleGlobal)
    
    app.use(routes)
    
    app.on('pronto', () => {
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log("Está rodando na porta 3000")
            console.log("Acesse http://localhost:3000")
        })
    })
```

Comment: you seem to be using `connect-mongodb-session` syntax but using `connect-mongo`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#usage), this should be the correct way to integrate `connect-mongo` with `express-session`:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'hdfkajdkk58fj',
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      httpOnly: true,
    },
  })
);
```